# Can I query a table in a database, only if it exists, within a view?

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, database-design, view

I am trying to standardise a view which is different between two customers. One of the differences is a LEFT JOIN to a table in a database which exists for only one of the customers, as it is only relevant to them. I don't want to have to create the database on the other customers server. I also want to avoid creating as another view as there are a lot of dependencies attached.

I have tried adding a SYNONYM but as the database and table doesn't exist on the other server, this causes an error.

I have tried to add logic into a view but a bit limited here.

```
CREATE TABLE #Product
(
    ProductID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    Product_Name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
)

INSERT #Product
(
    Product_Name
)
SELECT 'Example Product 1' UNION
SELECT 'Example Product 2' 

CREATE TABLE #CustomerDB_Product -- This is a replica of the table which exists in the customer specific database
(
    CustomerDBProductID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    CustomerDBProduct_Name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
)

INSERT #CustomerDB_Product
(
    CustomerDBProduct_Name
)
SELECT 'Example Customer Product 1'

SELECT  P.ProductID,
        MAX(P.Product_Name) AS Product_Name,
        MAX(CASE WHEN CP.CustomerDBProductID IS NOT NULL THEN CP.CustomerDBProduct_Name ELSE P.Product_Name END) AS CustomerProduct_Format
FROM    #Product P
        LEFT JOIN #CustomerDB_Product CP ON CP.CustomerDBProductID = P.ProductID
GROUP BY
        P.ProductID

-- DROP TABLE #Product
-- DROP TABLE #CustomerDB_Product
```

Where the customer specific database exists I would expect to see the `CustomerProduct_Format` column picking up data and where the customer specific database doesn't exist I would expect the `CustomerProduct_Format` column to be an exact match to the `Product_Name` column.

The proposed solution needs to be able to be written as a view.

Comment: A `VIEW` is simply a precompiled `SELECT` statement, it can't have any other internal logic. If an object a `VIEW` references doesn't exist, it will error; you can't avoid that. If the object might or might not exist it either sounds like you have a design problem, or you shouldn't be using a `VIEW`.

Comment: Thank you @Larnu for the confirmation! Looks like I have no choice but to split this out into another customer specific view, and go and amend all the dependencies.

Comment: @APC - because 'CustomerDB_Product' exists within a customer specific database which cannot be created on other customer servers. It doesn't exist within the database the query runs from. The reason it is in a separate database is because it is a completely separate app we are storing data for.

Comment: Okay, but can't you build a dummy of it? All you need is the one column.

Comment: If you can maintain a special table just for one specific customer, couldn't you maintain a special view just for that customer too? Or create two views, and just maintain a different _synonym_ for that customer.

Comment: @AaronBertrand that's what I am doing now, created a separate view just for this specific column for the one customer. You've got to love inheriting databases.

Answer (score 0):

What I meant by adding a synonym. For Customer A, you have a view that includes the tables or column that only exists for Customer A.

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.ViewForCustomerA
AS
  SELECT ... FROM <tables that exist for everyone>
             JOIN <table that only exists for CustomerA>;
GO
```

For everyone else (and even Customer A), you have a *different* view that doesn't include those objects:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.ViewForEveryoneElse
AS
  SELECT ... FROM <tables that exist for everyone>;
GO
```

Then, only in customer A's database, create a synonym that points to their special view:

```
CREATE SYNONYM dbo.ViewName FOR dbo.ViewForCustomerA;
```

And for everyone else, you create the same synonym, but point it at the view for everyone:

```
CREATE SYNONYM dbo.ViewName FOR dbo.ViewForEveryoneElse;
```

Now, all the rest of your code that references the underlying view, can instead reference `dbo.ViewName` - it will work regardless of which customer it is, saving a whole lot of hassle making all of your queries conditional or maintaining a messy slew of nested views.